# Laravel 5.5.23 Mongodb Authentication Failed Error

Tags: mongodb, php-7, laravel-5.5

I am using a Laravel 5.5.23 project with

> "jenssegers/mongodb": "^3.3"

PHP Mongodb version

> MongoDB extension version 1.3.4

PHP version

> PHP Version 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Mongodb version

> v3.4

I am getting Authentication failed error, although I can connect to remote mongo server from the same ec2 instance where the code resides

```
Authentication failed.
#0 /var/www/html/app-testproj/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/InsertOne.php(86): MongoDB\Driver\Server->executeBulkWrite('testproj_technog...', Object(MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite), Object(MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern))
#1 /var/www/html/app-testproj/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Collection.php(638): MongoDB\Operation\InsertOne->execute(Object(MongoDB\Driver\Server))
#2 [internal function]: MongoDB\Collection->insertOne(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/app-testproj/vendor/jenssegers/mongodb/src/Jenssegers/Mongodb/Collection.php(45): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/html/app-testproj/vendor/jenssegers/mongodb/src/Jenssegers/Mongodb/Query/Builder.php(567): Jenssegers\Mongodb\Collection->__call('insertOne', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/app-testproj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(1270): Jenssegers\Mongodb\Query\Builder->insertGetId(Array, '_id')
#6 /var/www/html/app-testproj/vendor/jenssegers/mongodb/src/Jenssegers/Mongodb/Eloquent/Builder.php(79): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->__call('insertGetId', Array)
#7 /var/www/html/app-testproj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(707): Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Builder->insertGetId(Array, '_id')
#8 /var/www/html/app-testproj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(672): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->insertAndSetId(Object(Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Builder), Array)
#9 /var/www/html/app-testproj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(535): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->performInsert(Object(Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Builder))
#10 /var/www/html/app-testproj/app/Infographics.php(27): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->save()
#11 /var/www/html/app-testproj/app/Console/Commands/SaveTechnographicSheetData.php(71): App\Infographics::saveData(Array)
#12 [internal function]: App\Console\Commands\SaveTechnographicSheetData->handle()
#13 /var/www/html/app-testproj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 /var/www/html/app-testproj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#15 /var/www/html/app-testproj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#16 /var/www/html/app-testproj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(549): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#17 /var/www/html/app-testproj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(180): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#18 /var/www/html/app-testproj/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(252): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#19 /var/www/html/app-testproj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(167): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#20 /var/www/html/app-testproj/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(918): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#21 /var/www/html/app-testproj/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(222): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(App\Console\Commands\SaveTechnographicSheetData), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#22 /var/www/html/app-testproj/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(129): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#23 /var/www/html/app-testproj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(88): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#24 /var/www/html/app-testproj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(121): Illuminate\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#25 /var/www/html/app-testproj/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#26 {main}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In mongo log getting error as "2017-12-10T05:00:35.597+0000 I ACCESS   [conn56675] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for myUser on admin from client 10.100.101.11 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user myUser@admin"

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you have authorization enabled your's mongo server.
for *nix

### Check mongo config at /etc/mongod.conf for authorize options.

security

### authorization: enabled

than check config for mondo modules connection at laravel. You need to set  optional optionб for security connection to mongo server.

```
'mongodb' => [
            'driver'   => 'mongodb',
            'host'     => 'HOST',
            'port'     => '27017',
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'pass',
            'database' => 'DB',
            'options' => [
                'db' => 'PUT_THERE_DB_NAME' //Sets the auth DB
            ]
```

Comment: Be aware that in the latest version the options have changed. 
It now has to be:
`'database' => 'PUT_THERE_DB_NAME'`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
'mongodb' => [
                'driver'   => 'mongodb',
                'host'     => 'HOST',
                'port'     => '27017',
                'username' => 'username',
                'password' => 'pass',
                'database' => 'DB',
                'options' => [
                    'database' => 'PUT_THERE_DB_NAME' //Sets the auth DB
                ]
```